# Update Data Extension with SQL Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a data extension (Name: Factura_T_Alex) with a single primary key (Name: NrFactura) and an attribute (Name: DataEmitere) which is a DateTime type. I need only the date part to use in a script so I created a Text type attribute (Name: DataEmitereText) in which I want to save only the date from DataEmitere so I wrote the folowing SQL Query:

```
SELECT
NrFactura,
CONVERT(varchar, DataEmitere, 101) AS DataEmitereText
FROM [Factura_T_Alex]
```

and **IT WORKS!**

But the targeted data extension for this is the same data extension I'm using in the SQL Query Activity, Factura_T_Alex, as seen in the image below.

[image: SQL Query]

***My question is***: Can I do that? Can I use the target data extension to update it's own fields in SQL and be sure that nothing will go wrong here? Like a field being written with the wrong value?

Comment: It would be much easier if you just converted the date using a dedicated function in your script - which scripting language are you using and what is the desired format of the date?

Comment: I'm already doing that. The script is complex and the DE has around 600k records, so I need the new text field to filter the records in the script to get only the records I need that day (around 50k per day).

Answer (score 0):

Going from your reply, you only need records for a certain day.

You could add the following WHERE-clause to your SQL query without the need to convert your date field:

```
WHERE Date(DataEmitere) = DATE(today())
```

For performance reasons, I would not recommend to convert your date field to text if you want to filter on it.